# Implicit conversion of constant

Tags: c++

Consider this simple code:

```
struct vec {
__m128 m128;
    inline operator __m128 &() {
        return m128;
    }
}
void someFunction(const vec &v) {
    someOtherFunction(v); //takes __m128 as argument
}
```

Whenever I call someFunction I get an error saying I can't convert from constant v to `__m128`

I've tried adding this to the struct

```
inline operator const __m128 &() {
    return m128;
}
```

but then I get errors everywhere saying "cant convert argument from vec to `__m128`

Comment: Have you tried changing the const qualifier on the operator itself? (i.e `inline operator const __m128& () const { ... }`.) With the second version you're returning a `const __m128`, but the function itself isn't "safe" to be called with const `vec`s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
struct vec
{
    __m128 m128;

    operator __m128&()
    {
        return m128;
    }

    operator const __m128&() const
    {
        return m128;
    }
};
```

Notice the double const in the second overload. The first const applies to the return value, the second one applies to the operator itself - it says that the operator can be called on const-qualified instances of the object.

Comment: works I just don't know why. I thought the const qualifier on functions meant that the "this" pointer doesn't exist and u can't access the class/struct, but you need to access to to return m128 don't you

Comment: You're confusing this with static methods. Static methods don't have a "this" pointer. Const methods do, but the "this" pointer is const (in this case, it would be `const vec* this`).

Comment: @Ragdoll const on member functions means the function doesn't modify the object. It allows the function to be called on const objects and references.